# Interactive math software for polynomial geometry

Tags: matlab, math-software, mathematica

I've found [this Wolfram Demonstrations applet illustrating Sendov's Conjecture](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SendovsConjecture/) very interesting to play around with and have been working on writing my own version in the MATLAB language. I thought that would be faster than learning to create interactive applets in Mathematica. Moreover, I have a free option, Octave, which uses the MATLAB language.

The shortfall of this is that, as far as I know, Octave doesn't support dynamic interactivity. I'm wondering what other free software is out there that would be better-suited to creating a program like the applet I linked to.

EDIT: To be more specific, by "dynamic" I'm thinking of the sort of drag-and-drop capabilities that Mathematica demonstrates in the link above. In that example, Mathematica reevaluates the polynomial's critical points in real time as a root is dragged.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Octave has nothing to do with Mathematica. It is a free program that tries to emulate Matlab. There is (to my surprise) a symbolic math package for Octave, which I have never tried.

Comment: I know Mathematica and Octave have no connection. I mentioned its connection to MATLAB in my original question. I've been using that simply because I'm already experienced with the MATLAB language but not with Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) is supposed to be (I think) the main free alternative to Mathematica.

You can use its online [cell server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to give it a quick try. I think it should be able to do applets and interactive things through *interact* (see [this question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/9014/are-there-options-for-interactivedynamic-content/) for example).

Good luck with that!

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful - I looked at its documentation and didn't see anything with the "dynamic" component of the sort of interactivity I'm hoping to find. I edited my question to make that a little clearer. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you check the interact functionality? Open the cell server (the link is on the question), open the question with the example (also linked in the question), then copy the code in the first answer and paste it in the cell server. Click on evaluate. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: It only updates after the user releases the slider, not in real time, so it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I agree with you that it is a desirable functionality. I am convinced that they are already working on that on Sage. Take a look at this [link](https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/future): I think that may be precisely what they mention in the fourth bullet point starting from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's about the closest I'll find right now. It was a 2013 post, though, so I won't hold my breath. I actually have thought about writing it in Pygame, which is event-based and could probably do the dynamic functionality more easily. I think my Octave version is sufficient for now, though, and relearning Python and learning the Pygame package would take too long in comparison to the benefit they'd add.